# Cloud Firestore document locking

Tags: database, firebase, transactions, locking, google-cloud-firestore

To ensure exclusive use of a Cloud Firestore document in a shared setting, is it sufficient to read, then write to a field (eg 'lockedBy') within a transaction?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Pessimistic vs Optimistic

There is no native exclusive locking in Cloud Firestore. As the system is designed to run in large distributed systems (e.g, 1000's of mobile phone users or a Kubernetes cluster), it is based around optimistic locking patterns.

This means that when you do a read-write transaction, if the document you read is written to before you can commit the transaction, the transaction will fail so the client can rollback.

### Building your own - Mobile SDKs & Security Rules

I'm going to assume you're coming in from a mobile SDK to start with, and will address server clients in the next section.

You can build an exclusive lock on top of this by using a separate document. For example, say you want to implement exclusive locking on documents in collection `critical_data`.

For this, we're going to use a separate collection called `mutex_critical_data`, with the documents inside being mutexes for documents with the same id in collection `critical_data`.

Before you can access a document called `doc_id` in `critical_data` you'll want to perform a write transaction to set the mutex field `owner` to you. I'll assume you're using Firebase Auth so you == the user's auth id `auth_id`. This can be any id that uniquely identifies the user or process though.

Once you are finished with the document, delete the mutex document so others can use it.

To ensure it's exclusive and other people cannot steal it, you'll want to add some checks in your security rules definition.

```
// In the match section that sets the document id to 'doc_id'
function mutex_exists ()
{
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/mutex_critical_data/$(doc_id));
}

function mutex_owner ()
{
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/mutex_critical_data/$(doc_id)).data;
}

function user_owns_mutex () {
    return mutex_owner().owner == request.auth.uid;
}

allow write: if not(mutex_exists()) || user_owns_mutex;
```

You can also use rules to enforce the mutex as well, by predicating writing to the resource by also owning the mutex.

### Building your own - Server Clients

Keep in mind that security rules are for Mobile/Web SDK access and aren't used for server clients. As server clients are considered a trusted environment, rather than having the exclusivity logic enforced by rules, you'll want to do the check in the read-write transaction on the mutex.

### Leases not Locks

Last point if you build this, is I'd highly recommend looking into exclusive leases rather than exclusive locks.

A lease is like a lock, but it automatically expires if the leasee doesn't (or isn't allowed) to renew the lease before a set time. This means if the client doesn't come back (e.g, client crashes), someone else will eventually be able to obtain the lease without administrator action.

The concept is the same, but rather than setting just the owner, you also set the lease time in a field. If the lease is greater than `x` old, where `x` is the time length of the lease, it is consider to no longer be held by the owner. Before the lease expires, you can optionally allow the owner to renew the lease by setting a new lease time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how to implement pessimistic locking. I can understand that this is required for critical applications. If we neglect malicious users, and assume all users check first using the same transaction, would a read-check-for-locked-field-write within a transaction be enough then? If its not enough, then I need to read more about the meaning of 'atomicity' in FireStore transactions.

Comment: Yes, assume trust that is sufficient

Comment: Hey @DanMcGrath, your answers are always great! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks @VictorNascimento! Glad you've found them helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to implement a lock at all if [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) do what you want. I was considering locking a document so that I could first check a field in that document before updating but Firestore Transactions allow me lock the document so that I can both read and update a document without any other process having access to that document.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Admin SDK (or corresponding REST API), one option for a global lock is to use the [create](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#create) method.

> ... This will fail the write if a document exists at its location.